# ModelBuilder: Make Feature Layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I have created a model that (I want) to take a point, selects the polygon it is within, selects a different point that is within the same polygon that contains the data I am after.  I then want to join the tables and get rid of unnecessary columns.  I have toggled the Field Info checkboxes in the Make Feature Layer tool, however, every time I run the model, those boxes reset.  I am assuming this is because the tables that I am trying to join and make into a feature layer are temporary, so when the Make Feature Tool is ran it is going to its default settings as it is looking at a new table every time.

How do I make the tables I am ultimately joining permanent?

[image]

Comment: `Join Field` is permanent, `Add Join` is temporary. If you want/need to use `Add Join`, then you'll have to save the results to disk.